# Error "authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream" on push notification

Tags: c#, ios

I am getting the below error when I send a push notification for IOS using c#

First error:

> An internal error occurred.at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.

when I changed the Application pool property(advance setting) identity to 'localsystem' then it started to shown below message.

> Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame

Comment: Have send pushnotification from SSL3

Comment: It errors on 1 notification send? or are you sending multiple notifications? Also have a read of https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/36e07df7-1d29-4b35-a6fe-6cbc8fc30208/authentication-failed-as-remote-party-has-closed-the-transport-stream?forum=netfxnetcom

Answer (score 0):

Apple News At `October 22, 2014` release that Apple Push Notification server will remove support for SSL 3.0

[Visit Apple Updates.](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10222014a)

Apple push servers no longer supports SSL3. Try change this to default and it's work properly.

Comment: In short you need to change your approach to send notification.

Comment: string regId = ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["RegistrationID"].ToString();
regId = regId.Replace(" ", "");
regId = regId.Replace("<", "");
regId = regId.Replace(">", "");
var payload11 = new NotificationPayload(regId, message, 1);
var notificationList1 = new List<NotificationPayload> { payload11 };  
string path1 = Server.MapPath(" ") + "\\KaraokeProductionCertificate.p12";
var push1 = new testpush.PushNotification(false, path1, "Krishna1234");
var rejected1 = push1.SendToApple(notificationList1);

Comment: did you please is there any SSL3 not used?